# Javascript Split properties into Object exclude inside Strings

Tags: javascript, css, regex

What is the best method for splitting or extracting the css properties out of as string and into an object?

```
var cssProperties = 'background:green;content:"Content;";color:pink;';
```

The above should result in the following

```
var theObject = {
    background:'green',
    content:'"Content;"',
    color:'pink'
}
```

Unfortunately I can not just use a split(";") and cycle through the array due to the semicolon in the url.  I could create a giant loop that cycles through every character while skipping the ";" only while wrapped in quotes, but that seems kinda of wrong.

Is there a regex trick for this?

Optional:
Also are there any really good regex websites.  I understand most of the syntax but there doesn't seem to be many practical really complicated examples on most of the websites I have found.

Comment: Why would you anticipate having a semicolon in the URL?

Comment: I am just trying to make it as fail proof as possible.

Comment: Could you put the CSS onto a new DOM element and then use the `.style` attribute to access it?

Comment: "content:'"Content;"')" this is not a valid key/value for a JS object.

Comment: Regexp isn't a parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle further demonstrating the function: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcEUL/

```
(function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        rprops =/[\w-]+(?=:)/g,
        rcamelCase = /-(\D)/g,
        fcamelCase = function(a,letter) {
                return letter.toUpperCase();
            };
    window['styleToObject'] = function(str) {
        var props = str.match(rprops),
            prop, i = 0,
            theObject = {};
        div.style.cssText = str;
        while (prop = props[i++]) {
            var style=div.style[prop.replace(rcamelCase,fcamelCase)];
            if (style) {
                theObject[prop] = style;
            }
        }
        return theObject;
    };
})();
```

Comment: +1 much better solution than mine. Though it failed getting background-color in IE because it didn't recognize it as a style. I updated your fiddle to camelCase the props and it worked in chrome/IE/opera/FF/safari but the props with a '-' become camelCased... http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/ACH9M/1/

Comment: Sweet! I had completely forgotten about camelCase in IE.  One edit though.  We can either move div var into the the styleToObject function or we need to delete setting div = null.  Just try running the styleToObject function twice.  It will through an error the 2nd time.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I went ahead and updated moving div into the function so it's all one block. I also left the div = null not sure if that's needed for garbage collection or not though... http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/ACH9M/3/

Answer (score 1):

Here was the solution I made regarding your first css string you had listed... Not the best but maybe it'll help spark some ideas.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/tZbeS/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this or something similar

```
var newString = cssProperties
                   .replace(":", ":'")
                   .replace(";", ", '");
var obj = eval(newString);
```